# I can't use arial in font-family?

Tags: css, fonts

Ever since I installed **Universal Type Font** on my work computer. All the fonts on my browsers are not a serif font. Even when I apply:

```
font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
```

It still renders as what looks like times new roman or a serif font.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Moe

Comment: You can use your browser toolkit (or better : firebug for mozilla) to see what font is really applied to your text.

Comment: You need to have Arial install on your computer to see it.

Comment: This worked. 'font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;